# Has the hot tab of the questions/ page been renamed to faq?

Tags: support, question-lists

I first saw it on the dba beta. But it seems to be in all sites?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. May I add I find this rename a bit confusing. My first thought was to find some questions mystically tagged as faq.

Comment: @bernd_k - Just joking. Your English is significantly better than my German :) Hmm I cant find any reasoning behind the rename but I guess they are classed as FAQ based on the fact they have been viewed a lot.

Comment: @Barry just took a look into the blog and found nothing about it. I'm still confused with FAQ I associate something more static.

Comment: @bernd_k - the hot tab is still there.  you have to go to http://stackoverflow.com not http://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: @bernd_k - the "faq" tab just lists question with the most links where as the "hot" tab lists questions with most views, answers, votes over the last few days.

Comment: If the first page of questions on the FAQ tab doesn't contain some variant of "why do I get 1 instead of 1.5 when I divide 3 by 2" then the *F* stands for something other than *frequently*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it hasn't been renamed. It did *displace* the hot view in the link bar, however.

You can still see the hot list in the Questions page by hand editing the URL:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot

(You'll see no tab appears selected. That's because the tab has been visually removed.)

Comment: well how come I don't see it on the SO homepage? Or am I just being blind? ~ EDIT ~ OOOOOOOOOOOOHhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I seeeeeee. When is this gonna be pushed to the "main page"?

Comment: @drachenstein as Barry found it is in the questions tab